# HTML To call .msg

Tags: html, button, outlook

I want to create a button using this code:

```
<p><button type="submit" formaction="/secondcb.msg">2nd Level CallBack</button></p>
```

but I want it to open an existing .msg (outlook saved item) file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you provide details on what concretely you have tried to solve this so others don't have to make the same mistakes. See also: [Help: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well i didnt do much just tried as a regular button. But i cant make it work.Hence i ask if anyone has any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Outlook applies restrictions on running any JS code inside mail items. You must develop a COM add-in if you want to do any actions programmatically in Outlook. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) for more information.

If you need to develop a JS/HTML based add-in you, see [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=yeomangenerator).